# Bash - How to find all files NOT in array

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have number of files in a directory and a list of expected files in it.

For example:
files I have are:

- file1
- file2
- file3

expected files are

- file1
- file2
- file4

I'd like to test the dir and find that file4 is NOT in it.

Comment: You have accepted an answer that shows you how to print all file names in an array that do not actually exist in your directory, which is quite the opposite of your question title (list names of files that exist but are not present in the array)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an array with the filenames and want to find out which ones are not present in the directory, just loop through the array, and check if the files exist. (`-f` tests for regular files, `-e` for any type)

```
files=(file1 file2 file4)
for f in "${files[@]}" ; do 
    [ -f "$f" ] || echo "$f: not found"
done
```

---

The opposite is similar, but requires a double-loop or turning the array into an associative array. With the double-loop:

```
files=(file1 file2 file4)
for f in * ; do
        found=0
        for g in "${files[@]}" ; do
                [ "$f" = "$g" ] && found=1
        done
        [ "$found" = 0 ] && echo "$f: in directory but not listed"
done
```

Comment: `ls -ld "${array[@]}" 1>/dev/null`  would be a quick and dirty way to do it although that doesn't make any distinction between regular files and the rest...

Comment: Strictly speaking, `-f` is _regular file or symlink to regular file that can be `stat()`ed_ and `-e` for _files (of any type) that can be `stat()`ed_. See also `[ -e "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ]` (or `ls -d -- "$file"`) for _files of any type that can be `lstat()`ed_. For _directory entries_, you could use globbing.

Comment: Just to be clear - my comment on the question was an (ignored, apparently) attempt to convince the OP to clarify the question and fix the title. Your initial answer was (and still is)  fine as far as I am concerned (it shows the canonical way to print the elements of an array which do not exist as file names)

Comment: @don_crissti, yeah, I didn't take it like that, I just noticed the difference (which I missed when first writing the answer), but didn't want to stomp on the question either. So adding the answer to the other question was the obvious other thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

For array union and subtraction, look at `zsh` instead of `bash`.

```
$ expected=(file1 file2 file4)
$ existing=(file1 file2 file3) # or existing=(file*) to use globbing

$ echo missing: ${expected:|existing}
missing: file4
$ echo found: ${expected:*existing}
found: file1 file2
$ echo unexpected: ${existing:|expected}
unexpected: file3
```

Mnemonic (mine at least, I don't know if they are the official ones):

- `${A:|B}`: elements of `$A` *bar* those of `$B`
- `${A:*B}`: elements of `$A` *starring* those of `$B`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got to test for a bunch of files, then a function is a better solution. Otherwise, a simple `ls` of the file will suffice! Below is the output you will get when the file you're looking for isn't there:

```
../theDirIWantToCheck $ ls theFileIWantToFind.txt
ls: theFileIWantToFind.txt: No such file or directory
```

I would also recommend utilizing tab-completion. Give the `ls` command and then start typing the name of any file you expect. You only have to give a few characters and then press tab (if that doesn't work, press tab twice). All file names matching that pattern will be presented **if they exist.**

```
$ ls fi<tab>
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file_new.txt filetypes.txt
```

You can also pass `ls` multiple arguments to check on multiple files:

```
$ ls file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
...
```

If the files share the same pattern prefix (such as above: file1, file2, file3), you can use brace expansion. This is like passing all three arguments in a condensed form. The `..` represents a range.

```
$ ls file{1..3}.txt
ls: file1.txt: No such file or directory
ls: file2.txt: No such file or directory
ls: file3.txt: No such file or directory
```

Alternatively, you could use a wildcard to pass all the possible matching patterns with the common prefix "file" (such as file1.txt, file_other.txt):

```
$ ls file*
...
```

Finally, you can pass all the arguments in an array to `ls` and let it do the printing for you, rather than using `echo`. What's more, if you use the `-l` option to `ls`, when the files do exist, you can get some extra details about them, such as permissions, file size, and last modification date/time.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -le '-e or print for qw/file1 file2 file4/'
```