# Bash - How to make a function "delete only non-matching array from user inputs"

Tags: bash, shell-script, delete, bash-array

Suppose, I have 1 file in a folder named `B.py`

Using this script, I make 3 files within that folder. The files are `A.py B.py C.py`.

```
read -r -p "Enter the filenames: " -a arr
for filenames in "${arr[@]}"; do
   if [[ -e "${filenames}" ]]; then
        echo "${filenames} file exists (no override)"
   else
        cp -n ~/Documents/library/normal.py "${filenames}" && echo "${filenames} file created"
   fi
done
```

Among them, `A.py` and `C.py` are created with `normal.py` template while `B.py` stays the same.

Now, I **want a function to delete** `A.py` and `C.py` (newly created ones). 
not override ones won't be deleted

How can I filter this from the array?

PS: I'm still a noob. Couldn't implement this feature in my script. 
The script should delete like this `rm -i {A,C}.py`

Saw this thread here 
[Bash - How to find all files NOT in array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354419/bash-how-to-find-all-files-not-in-array)

**Note:** User inputs is undefined not three.

Comment: I think the problem is that there isn't a really neat way to check whether a string is in an array since bash isn't a high level programming language (I think even with Java or so you need to use a "Collection" or sort of convert the array into one first.). See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value) gives you some insight. (I do not particularly endorse any of the approach in it; some of them might be "dirty".) Another approach might be forming a `find` command (with some `-name` negation) with the user input.

Comment: @TomYan it doesn't matter if it's dirty. Plz, i need this to work.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is delete all `.py` files in the current directory that are an **exact copy** of `~/Documents/library/normal.py`, then you can do something like this:

```bash
for f in ./*.py; do
  if cmp ~/Documents/library/normal.py "$f"; then
    rm "$f"
  fi
done
```

This uses `cmp` to compare each file `$f` against normal.py.  If and only if `cmp` returns 0 (true) then "$f" is deleted.

See `man cmp` for details.

Be careful not to run it in your ~/Documents/library directory. Here's a version that guards against that:

```bash
src_file=~/Documents/library/normal.py
src_dir=$(dirname "$src_file")

if [ "$(realpath -e ./)" = "$(realpath -e "$src_dir")" ] ; then
  echo "Warning: This script is NOT safe to run in the same directory as $src_file" >&2
  exit 1
fi

for f in ./*.py; do
  if cmp "$src_file" "$f"; then
    rm "$f"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If switching to `zsh` is an option:

```
arr=()
# use vared instead of read for the user to be able to enter
# arbitrary file names including some with whitespace of newlines
# by using \ (and also allows some user friendly editing).
vared -p 'Enter the filenames: ' arr

files=(*(ND)) # files including hidden ones in the current directory

for file ${arr:|files}; do # loop over elements of arr *bar* those of files
  cp -n -- $template $file
done
```

Then to delete the files that are not in `$var`, it's just:

```
rm -f -- ${files:|arr}
```

It's also possible to check whether a file is member of an array as part of a glob qualifier:

```
rm -f -- *.py(e['(( ! $arr[(Ie)$REPLY] ))'])
```

Would remove the non-hidden `.py` files that are not found by name `e`xactly as any element of the `$arr` array for instance.

`$arr[(I)pattern]` expands to the index of the last array element that matches the pattern or 0 if none is found. The `e` flag does an exact match (no pattern matching).